# Twilio Android get user presence

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api, videochat

I'm using the Twilio for make video calls on android app and I have one question.
For I make a room I create with the first user and the second user connect with room name. But how I can do this room "automatically" and send invitation for another user? 
Example: I click on my friend pic and this start a invitation for him, him receive and accept the invitation and video calls start..

Answer (score 1):

The Twilio Programmable Video API is not a direct interface for making video calls. The API simply handles the rooms, so you need to handle the calling and receiving on your end. The best way of doing this is using a Push Notification service such as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client). When a user makes a call, send a notification to another user that they are receiving a call.

Once the user is in the room, you can monitor when they disconnect and then end the call through that. Learn more about room participants [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms).

Comment: How do I send a json to the other user? I mean, I thought about creating the room automatically on the backend and using a json return to simulate that invitation.

Comment: If you initiate a call on one device, the best (and most efficient) way of letting the other participant device receive the call is push notifications such as Firebase Cloud Messaging mentioned above.